# Como impedir que um addEventListener seja executado várias vezes em uma função?

Tags: javascript, ionic, typescript, ionic3, javascript-eventos

Tenho uma função que exibe um determinado anúncio ao usuário no aplicativo. Após visualização desse anúncio, eu chamo um addEventListener, que passa um evento CLOSE. Após esse evento CLOSE ser acionado, o usuário é recompensado pelo vídeo (conforme comentei no trecho de código).

O que ocorre : Quando vejo um vídeo, ele adiciona a recompensa normalmente, apenas uma vez como deve ser. Porém quando eu vejo o segundo vídeo, ele adiciona a recompensa duas vezes, então entendo que o evento está sendo executado duas vezes na segunda vez, é como se ele estivesse "guardando" o evento anterior, e chamando o evento novo. Se vejo pela terceira vez, acontece o mesmo, ele aciona o evento 3 vezes, e adiciona a recompensa 3 vezes lá no banco de dados.

Como eu posso fazer a tratativa desse evento, de forma que : O usuário vê um vídeo, envia a recompensa para o banco, mata o evento. O usuário vê o segundo vídeo, aciona o evento apenas uma vez, e envia a recompensa (uma recompensa) ao banco de dados, e assim por diante.

Segue o trecho do meu código :

```
//Vídeos da Inmobi
videosInmobi() {
    let carregar = this.loading.create({content : "Carregando..."});
    carregar.present();
    let rewardConfig: AdMobFreeRewardVideoConfig = {
        isTesting: true,
        autoShow: true,
        id: 'ca-app-pub-8000726989219599/6974786599' //id videos InMobi
    };
    this.admob.rewardVideo.config(rewardConfig);
    this.admob.rewardVideo.prepare().then(() => {
        carregar.dismissAll();
    })
    //Após o usuario assistir o vídeo, chamo esse evento CLOSE, que fecha o video e executa a função
    //this.addReward(); que envia o valor da recompensa ao banco de dados.
    document.addEventListener('admob.rewardvideo.events.CLOSE', () => {
        this.recompensa.data = moment().format('L'); //aqui recebe a data da recompensa
        this.recompensa.valor = 0.02; //aqui recebe 2 centavos a cada recompensa, esse valor é enviado ao banco
        console.log('valor da recompensa : ' +this.recompensa.valor);
        console.log('data : ' +this.recompensa.data);
        this.addReward();
    });       
}
```

imagem em anexo para explicar melhor o que está ocorrendo :

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Obs : Estou trabalhando com ionic3, mas este plugin específico é js puro.

Comment: Ao invés de adicionar a função diretamente no `addEventListener`, use uma variável para representar a função e utilize o `removeEventListener` para remover a função e adicionar outra. Ou (ainda mais simples), utilize a função `admob.rewardvideo.events.CLOSE` fora da função `videosInmobi`

Comment: Eu agradeço a cooperação e a vontade em ajudar.
Um abraço e obrigado mais uma vez.

Comment: "*é como se ele estivesse "guardando" o evento anterior*" - sim, `addEventListener` é acumulativo, se adicionar vários listeners, ele vai executar todos. Uma alternativa é usar a opção `once`, que aí ele só roda uma vez e é removido em seguida - ver mais [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34325394) e [aqui](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#parameters)

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que me recordo, não há maneira de checar a existência de um ouvinte de um evento.
No caso, cada vez que a função `addEventListener` é chamada, você adiciona mais uma função anônima (seu caso) para ser chamada em sequencia. Ou seja, cada recompensa, você terá mais um evento sendo chamado. Você teria que chamar a `addEventListener` fazer isto somente uma vez

1. Você pode tentar adicionar um valor booleano se foi adicionado ou não o evento (lembrando que não pode ser uma variável de escopo).
2. Chamar a `document.addEventListener('admob.rewardvideo.events.CLOSE', () =` na inicialização da página, onde ela seria chamada somente uma vez.
3. Existe também a função [`document.removeEventListener`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_removeeventlistener.asp) que faz exatamente o contrário do 'addEventListener' só que não funciona com funções anônimas, então, teria que criar uma função externa.

Dê uma olhada neste link : [How to check wheter dynamically attached event listener exists or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11455515/how-to-check-whether-dynamically-attached-event-listener-exists-or-not)

PS: Desculpe não dar códigos de exemplo, não sou da área do javascript mas tentei ajudar com alguma informação.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, consegui entender sua explicação e resolver o problema aqui. Um abraço e obrigado pela vontade em ajudar e cooperação.

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver a questão chamando o addEventListener no carregamento da página conforme o sugerido.

Então o código ficou assim :

```
    ionViewWillEnter() {
    this.showBanner();
    document.addEventListener('admob.rewardvideo.events.CLOSE', () => {
        this.recompensa.data = moment().format('L'); //aqui recebe a data da recompensa
        this.recompensa.valor = 0.02; //aqui recebe 2 centavos a cada recompensa, esse valor é enviado ao banco
        console.log('valor da recompensa : ' +this.recompensa.valor);
        console.log('data : ' +this.recompensa.data);
        this.addReward();
    });  
}
```